# Does ASP Classic use reflection?

Tags: reflection, asp-classic, xss

I saw a piece of ASP code that looks as follows:

```
<% rs("Server.HTMLEncode(x)") %>
```

Since I doubt that the recordset has a field named "Server.HTMLEncode(x)" I was wondering if they meant to write:

```
<% Server.HTMLEncode(rs(x)) %>
```

Or if classic ASP does reflection and somehow interprets that string literal as a method call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used classic ASP for ten years, and I never encountered any kind of reflection.  Based on my past experience, I would agree with you that they probably meant to write:

```
<% Server.HTMLEncode(rs(x)) %>
```

But, it still does not look correct.  Did they mean to write out the value using Response.Write?  I can't tell without seeing more of the code.

Looks like bad coding to me.

Answer (score 0):

Classic ASP can be written with VBScript which *does* allow kind of reflection by using `Eval()` and `Execute()` methods. For example:

```
Class Foo
    Public Bar
End Class

Dim oFoo, propName, myValue
Set oFoo = New Foo
oFoo.Bar = "hello world"
propName = "Bar"
myValue = Eval("oFoo." & propName)
Response.Write("Value of " & propName & ":" & myValue)
```

However, **that's not the case** with your sample code. This is just a string literal passed to the Recordset object which looks for exact match. If the given parameter is a number it will return value of field having such index otherwise it expects a string which is exact field name.

Assuming `x` is user input that should be a field name or index, they probably meant:

```
<%=rs(Server.HTMLEncode(x)) %>
```